# Redefining latent variables as observed data

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, likelihood, posterior, gaussian-mixture-distribution

This was just a thought that occurred to me, but technically, is it possible to redefine what I treat as latent variables and what I treat as data?

For example, lets assume I have a set of latent variables that can describe 2 datasets equally well (but datasets origin form 2 different distributions). Now I am interested what part of my latent variables is better associated with which distribution. Could I simply treat those latent variables as my dataset, and the distributions as my latent variables?

or in general, if I have a likelihood p(y|z) (described by some gaussian distribution) computed using some model. If I change my problem statement could I redefine this likelihood to be a posterior?

Comment: If variables are latent, it means they are not observed so your proposal is unclear. Latent variables can be treated as parameters, instead.

Comment: I predicted those latent variables using another model and then treat them as observables. If that makes sense

Comment: I would rather aggregate both models rather than using plugg-in as a proxy to the latent variables.